# How to get the number of views, likes on a youtube video programmatically

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am trying to get the number of views, likes, and the number of comments on a youtube video in my app. 
I think there may be some trick to achieve it. I have a URL of my youtube video and want to use that URL for fetching these details from youtube.

I make some searches for this but I only get the answer like this "How to upload video programmatically" which is not my requirement.

Comment: YouTube has an API.. Have you researched that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the Youtube API:
read this because the example is exactly what you need:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

you are looking for the statistics region of the API response:

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
  },
```

good luck ;)